# batch file to set two variables from the first two lines of a file then move files

Tags: batch-file

From time to time, I need to move files. I save all the file names in a file. It's easy to write a batch file to read the file names and move them. In my case, the source and destination directories change often. Thus, I would like to put them in the first two lines of the file. How does one write a batch file to do that? I use "set /p" but it seems to read only one variable. The file looks something like this:

```
source directory
destination directory
file1
file2
file3
file4
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use for example this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Source="
set "Destination="
set "Line=1"
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("ListFile.txt") do (
    if !Line! GTR 2 (
        move /Y "!Source!\%%~I" "!Destination!\%%~I"
    ) else if !Line! == 1 (
        set "Source=%%~I"
        set "Line=2"
    ) else (
        set "Destination=%%~I"
        set "Line=3"
    )
    rem set /A Line+=1
)
endlocal
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `set /?`

Remove the line `rem set /A Line+=1` demonstrating another method of increasing line number during processing the lines from the list file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `set /p` to retrieve the two first lines of the file, you must execute the two reads *while keeping the redirection open* so the second read will retrieve the next line.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Prepare variables to hold data
    set "inputFile=config.txt"
    set "sourceDir="
    set "targetDir="

    rem Read first two lines of the input file
    < "%inputFile%" (
        set /p "sourceDir=" 
        set /p "targetDir=" 
    )

    rem Check we have the required information
    if not defined sourceDir goto :eof
    if not defined targetDir goto :eof

    rem Process the config file skipping the first two lines
    for /f "usebackq skip=2 delims=" %%a in ("%inputFile%") do (
        echo move "%sourceDir%.\%%a" "%targetDir%"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This method use `findstr /N` command to numerate the lines. The `for /F` command get the number in `%%a` and the line in `%%b`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" theFile.txt') do (
   if %%a leq 2 (
      set "line%%a=%%b"
   ) else (
      move "!line1!\%%b" "!line2!"
   )
)
```